# SQL - How to create T-SQL of Count with like

Tags: sql-server

I have data

```
ID       Group  Status
0001     A      T
0002     B      T
0003     AA     T
0004     C      T
0005     AAB    T
0006     CC     T 
0007     CCA    T
0008     CCAA   T
0009     AABA   F
0010     BA     F
```

and I want to count how many ID with the same (like) group and exclude F Status
For Ex : 0001 have group A, and 0003 (AA), 0005 (AAB) is the same group because its refer to A. 0009 (AABA) is also under 0001 but the status is F

```
ID       CountofGroup  
0001     2                 
0002     0      
0003     1     
0004     3      
0005     0   
0006     2      
0007     1    
0008     0   

0009      Status F
0010      Status F
```

Can you guys help me on this ?
Appreciate with your help

Comment: What will be with `AABB`? Does it belong to `A` or `B`? Or does `ACAB` belong to `AC` or `CAB` or may be to `ACA`? Elaborate on your questions. it is totally unclear what your `LIKE` means.

Comment: its like organization structure. A - AA - AABB. So AABB Belong to AA and A, AA belong to A

Comment: I can create query like this. 
select  count (*) group from table A where group like 'A%'. So the result  will be 2. But I dont know how to create a table which is look up the ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

**Query:**

```
Select d1.ID
    , CASE WHEN d1.[Status] = 'F' THEN 'Status F' 
        ELSE CAST(COUNT(d2.ID) as varchar(10)) 
    END
FROM @data d1
LEFT JOIN @data d2 
    ON d2.[Group] LIKE d1.[Group]+'%' 
        AND d2.[Group] <> d1.[Group] 
        AND d2.Status <> 'F'
GROUP BY d1.ID, d1.[Status]
ORDER BY d1.ID
```

I am not sure there is no duplicate such as 'AA' twice or more. Therefore I test on `d2.[Group] <> d1.[Group]` rather than `d2.[ID] <> d1.[ID]`. If there is no duplicate it is more efficient to test on `[ID]`.

**Data:**

```
DECLARE @data TABLE([ID] int, [Group] varchar(4), [Status] varchar(1));

INSERT INTO @data([ID], [Group], [Status])
VALUES
    (0001, 'A', 'T'),
    (0002, 'B', 'T'),
    (0003, 'AA', 'T'),
    (0004, 'C', 'T'),
    (0005, 'AAB', 'T'),
    (0006, 'CC', 'T'),
    (0007, 'CCA', 'T'),
    (0008, 'CCAA', 'T'),
    (0009, 'AABA', 'F'),
    (0010, 'BA', 'F')
;
```

**Output:**

```
ID  Count
1   2
2   0
3   1
4   3
5   0
6   2
7   1
8   0
9   Status F
10  Status F
```

Comment: Forgot d2.ID != d1.ID - author not count d1.ID in COUNT

Comment: Totally same query as in my answer - so you (author) can get it as ready to use and invariant thing

Comment: I prefer to look for different group. Perhaps there could be A more than once so test on ID is not enough in this case.

Comment: Well, maybe like this one.
My ID is 0001 and I have group name is A, and I have a member under me called 0002 so I give him group name is AA, and the 0002 have a member under him called 0003 so I will give group name AAC.

So I will know how many member under me just looking group name starting from A. And if I want to know how many member under 0002 just looking group name start from AA.

Comment: @Фагим Садыков I am not sure I understand your second comment correctly. If you mean I copied your query, you should first fix your own query. I was working on my own query and posted only 2 mins after you.

Comment: Funny fact, this will not work for all collations. In Danish_Norwegian 'aa' like 'a%' returns 0 rows. Example: SELECT 1 WHERE 'aa' collate Danish_Norwegian_CI_AS like 'a%'

Comment: Does 'aa' has a special meaning in Danish? BTW 'AABCD...' is probably not the best design for such hierarchy.

Comment: the last 3 letters in danish alphabet are 'æøå' those letters can be written 'ae','oe' and 'aa'. Which sometimes results in silly results when comparing.

Comment: I just trying your query and the result is correct. But The query takes long execution. DO you know why ? My table list is about 310.000 record

Comment: Can you update your question with the definition of your table, primary key and index? and add the execution plan if possible. An index on group  including id if it isnt a clustered pk already and where d2.Status <> 'F' would probably help.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple correlated subquery should work for you:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM @t 
           WHERE [Status] = 'T' AND ID <> t.ID AND [Group] LIKE t.[Group] + '%') As CountofGroup
FROM @t t
```

Comment: Thanks for the answering, I just try your query and the result is correct, but same as Julien, the query takes long. It looks like calculating one by one
the record is about 310.000 row.
Do you know why ?
I am still curious about this one

Comment: @Henry, you need iundex on Status column and group column

Comment: I already tried but still slow. I will trying using OLTP table and also index, hopefully faster

Answer (score -2):

Something like this:

```
select t.ID, count(t2.ID) from 
    mytable t join mytable t2 on ( 
        t2.Group like t1.Group + '%'
        and
        t2.ID != t1.ID 
        /* it's required without it it will count itself +1 time*/
)
where t1.Status = 'T' and t2.Status = 'T' 
group by t.ID
order by t.ID
```

```

While T-SQL is not familiar for you, notice:

1)

`mytable t1 join mytable t2  -- replace mytable with your table name`

Do not fear that mytable is referenced twice - it's logical by you requirements - you want get data from mytable and then compare it with mytable

2) 
We don't know how many data is processed - if it's 10 - 100000 rows - this query will be usefull- if more - may be some corrections and optimizations are required

3) 
We don't know is where indexes in your table.
Here - better to make indexes for Group and Status field and check if ID is real primary key

Comment: Suggestion - always use path like format to describe tree structures. Use /A/B/C/ with trail slashes instead of ABC because such mask can contains not just 1-letter keys, it can always be checked with %/XXX/% or /A/XXX/% without thinking about is it at end or at start of string.

Comment: You have many errors in your code. Group is a reserved word that you should wrap, you need left join instead of join, you have wrong table aliases and your where statement should be part of the left join. Not the same as Juliens answer which actually works

Comment: 1) so i write "something like this" and was written from Phone and some mistakes are not much sin. 2) Left join is not required here while it doesnt deal with null posibility at right side at all - full inner join will do same 3) where statement is not require be in join except of cases that it's left (here it's full inner) 4)  i have post my answer first as you can see - i could not know that Juliencs will answer, but want to provide helper hint for author. 5) Your (-1) is just sign of your bad manner and not much competence man

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you. But your rude response combined with the incorrect answer made me downvote now